# Spring-MVC : Testing with selenium failing with commons-io not found(it exists)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, selenium

I am trying my hands on testing a Spring-MVC application with Selenium. Unfortunately, I don't have much luck as of yet in getting it up and running. When I try to run it with a clean tomcat with following command, then it complains that the commons-io is not found.

If I directly start the test, then the login page is not loaded.

Starting apache :

```
mvn clean tomcat7:run
```

Error log :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) on project SOFTWARE: Could not start Tomcat: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: A child container failed during start -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Exception in thread "Thread-33" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.RunMojo$2.run(RunMojo.java:295)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
```

POM.xml with commons-io :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            </archive>
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

If i directly try to give the following command :

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=SeleniumLoginFrontendTest
```

The login page is not loaded, and I get this error :

```
Tests in error: 
  SeleniumLoginFrontendTest.startTest:25 » NoSuchElement Unable to locate elemen...
```

SeleniumLoginFrontendTest.java :

```
  public class SeleniumLoginFrontendTest  {

        private WebDriver browser;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        @Test
        public void startTest() {
            browser.get("http://localhost:8080/login");
      --> Below is line-25  

browser.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("");
        browser.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("");

            browser.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
            browser.findElement(By.id("account")).click();
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() {
          //  browser.close();
        }

    }
```

So, what exactly am I doing wrong? Any help would be nice. Thank you. :-)

*Update*
So, I did set the commons-io library to version 2.2, but that did not help.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why was this downvoted? I think SO should make it compulsory that a comment be posted when user downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly specify a version:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: No-change, ran `mvn clean && mvn install` before running `mvn clean tomcat7:run`. Same error.

Comment: The test runs and it fails, only that error. If I run my project without the test, then it's no problem.

Comment: I found that tomcat7 plugin needs this dependency:
`<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: add  the appropriate  version to your `commons-io` with verifying that the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` exists in the version of the jar `commons-io` because the class is missing

Comment: All dependencies must be in a single <dependencies> section

Comment: But your answer indicates that I have to create a new dependencies section, which is not allowed. Then I added a dependency in the already existing dependencies section, I get complain that its a duplicate one, and still fails with same error. I have all other dependencies in one dependencies section. Can you give me an example of POM.xml how it should be?

Comment: My answer indicates that you should specify version.
I can't see you full `pom.xml` file and don't know are your dependency is inside or `<dependencies>` block or not. That's why I explicitly specified it. Can you give me your full `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Yes. I tried by explicitly specifying as well. With and without duplicate dependencies, didn't help. here is my POM.xml : http://pastebin.com/WVsqs0aA

Comment: There are version `2.3` in your pom but must be `2.2`. If it will not help, try to check dependencies of your parent pom file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106238/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-kirill).